# Recursion in Ruby isnt working like I think it should

Tags: ruby, recursion

I don't understand why this method isn't working. when I put in a value that should pass the if statement it doesn't work.

```
def getBase
    puts "What is the base URL for the test?"
    x = gets
    if (x.include? 'http://') && ((x.split('.').at(x.split('.').length - 1).length) == 3)
      return x
    else
      puts "That is in the incorrect format."
      puts "Please format your url like this"
      puts "http://example.com"
      getBase
    end
end
```

input 'http://test.com'

result: statement repeats and does not exit recursion

Comment: We need more information. What is your test input? What is the result? Why do you expect it to work that way? Your `if` condition is pretty messy — what are you trying to do with it?

Comment: I expected x to be returned after a number of failed attempts. I have tested both conditions on each side of the && they seem to work the way I think they do.

Comment: IMO, this is not a particularly good place to use recursion... it's fine if it's just an example, but if all you're doing is waiting until the user finally inputs a valid text string why don't you use a loop? Also, it runs fine for me if I replace your conditional with one that works (`/^http:\/\/(.+\.)+.+$/.match(x)`, for example), and the reason for that is explained in iamnotmaynard's post.

Comment: @mdunsmuir I like this regex for this purpose (OP is trying to ensure that the top-level domain is three characters, I think): `/^http:\/\/.*\....$/`

Comment: If the purpose of that `if` condition is to ensure that the url ends in ".com", ".net", etc., it should be noted that there are other valid domains such as ".info" and ".us".

Comment: btw. if I see it right x.split('.').at(x.split('.').length - 1) is the same like x.split(".")[-1]. The condition would even more clearer, if you would use a regexp. In your case it could be something like this: x.match(/\Ahttp:\/\/(?:[\w-]+\.)+[\w]{3}\z/)

Comment: I considered the case of .us & .co.  but since this was more a thought exorcize I'm just glad I got the recursion to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get input with `gets` it includes the newline `\n` at the end (from the user hitting return). So your `x` is actually `"http://test.com\n"`.

To get rid of this use [`String#chomp`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-chomp):

```
x = gets.chomp
```

That should do it.

Comment: Also, I think he should be `return`ing the `getBase` call in the `else` statement...

Comment: the return in the else is implicit

Comment: That would make it more clear, but it's not necessary since Ruby automatically returns the last statement.

Answer (score 1):

If the purpose is to enforce correct URL format and/or make sure it's an HTTP URL, why don't you use a tool designed to do that? Ruby's [URI](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/index.html) class is your friend:

```
require 'uri'

URI.parse('http://foo.bar').is_a?(URI::HTTP)
=> true

URI.parse('ftp://foo.bar').is_a?(URI::HTTP)
=> false

URI.parse('file://foo.bar').is_a?(URI::HTTP)
=> false

URI.parse('foo.bar').is_a?(URI::HTTP)
=> false
```

I'd write the code more like this:

```
require 'uri'

def get_base
  loop do
    puts "What is the base URL for the test?"
    x = gets.chomp
    begin
      uri = URI.parse(x)
      return uri.to_s if uri.is_a?(URI::HTTP)
    rescue URI::InvalidURIError
    end
    puts "That is in the incorrect format."
    puts "Please format your URL like this:"
    puts
    puts "    http://example.com"
  end
end

puts "Got: #{ get_base() }"
```